# Display elements with id matching select value and hide others

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen a few solutions for showing/hiding elements based on a select but I think I need something more efficient

I need all divs to be displayed until a select input is changed. On change I need only elements with the matching id to be shown and all else to be hidden unless they match another dropdown (potentially 3 inputs)

I know it uses "this.value" but I'm not sure how to combine this with the display function

For those crying out for code here is the dropdown and the corresponding elements which should all be displayed as default but hidden as and when not selected

```
<select name="dataSelect" id="dataSelect" class="enter-drop" required>
<option value="" disabled>Data Amount</option>
<option value="any" selected>Any</option>
<option value="30">30GB</option>
<option value="12">12GB</option>
<option value="8">8GB</option>
</select>

<div id="30" class="deal">30GB of Data</div>
<div id="12" class="deal">12GB of Data</div>
<div id="8" class="deal">8GB of Data</div>
```

Comment: Code, code and once more, CODE! We need sample code, show us what you did and where you encountered your problem.

Comment: @Oen44 did you forget your magic wand again? How often do I have to tell you to bring it when answering SO questions!! ;-)

Comment: Are you using jquery? Also could you post a snippet demonstrating what you have and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: "_I think I need something more efficient_" Since you don't have any implementation yet, how/why would you think this?

Comment: Post some code so we can improvise it. We cant write the code from scratch for you, sorry.

Comment: @Oen44 Added, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JavaScript. There is no need of using IDs for every `div` element. Better use `data` attribute.

```js
document.getElementById('dataSelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-amount]");
  var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (selected.value == "any") {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      nodes[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      nodes[i].style.display = (nodes[i].dataset.amount == selected.value) ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<select name="dataSelect" id="dataSelect" class="enter-drop" required>
<option value="" disabled>Data Amount</option>
<option value="any" selected>Any</option>
<option value="30">30GB</option>
<option value="12">12GB</option>
<option value="8">8GB</option>
</select>

<div data-amount="30" class="deal">30GB of Data</div>
<div data-amount="12" class="deal">12GB of Data</div>
<div data-amount="8" class="deal">8GB of Data</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution, or at least possible minimum example of what I think you mean.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#selector').on('input', function() {
      var comp = $(this).val()
    $('div').each(function(i, el) {
      if (el.id == comp){
        $(el).show()
      } else {
        $(el).hide()
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option>
</select>

<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
<div id="d">D</div>
```

Comment: While the snippet works in situ, I've just tried implementing it but it seems to set ALL elements to hidden across the page rather than those not selected from the dropdown.

Comment: Where do you see `jQuery` tag? OP didn't ask for jQuery but JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
<sacript>
$('select[name=mySel]').change(function(){
   $('div').css('display','none');
   var id = $(this).val();
   $('div[id='+id+']').css('display','block');
})
</sacript>
<select name="mySel">
    <option value="myID1">myID1</option>
    <option value="myID2">myID2</option>
    <option value="myID3">myID3</option>
    <option value="myID4">myID4</option>
    <option value="myID5">myID5</option>
</select>

<div id="myID1">content1</div>
<div id="myID2">content2</div>
<div id="myID3">content3</div>
<div id="myID4">content4</div>
<div id="myID5">content5</div>
```

Comment: There is no `jQuery` tag and OP didn't say that he wants to use `jQuery`.